# Opening new tab from Chrome Extension to search in Google

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The idea was to make a simple Chrome Extension to make a Google search on the specific site instead of writing a site:whatever.whatever in a Google search field.
Here's my popup.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTP Searcher Extension's Popup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get" target="_blank" onsubmit="companiesSearch()">
        <input type="text" id="finalquery" name="q" value="" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" id="site" name="othername" value=" site:www.park.by" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" id="entertext" name="entertext">
        <input type="submit" class="sendsubmit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And popup.js:

```
function companiesSearch() {
    var value1 = document.getElementById('entertext').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('site').value;
    var value3 = value1 + value2;
    document.getElementById('finalquery').setAttribute('value', value3);
}
```

If to make a simple html file + js file like in the construction above, everything works smoothly. If to make it an extension, it works only without adding javascript: if to make an easy one input form it opens a new tab and shoes the search results. But after adding a script and after submit the search request blinks in the url line and than an empty Google search appears. Such error can by seen in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request scheme 'chrome-extension' is unsupported
at newtab-serviceworker.js:61
at <anonymous>
```

By the way, my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "HTP Searcher",
    "description": "This extension searches companies",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
    ]
}
```

Thank everyone in advance, completely new to writing extensions.

Comment: Inline js doesn't work in extension pages by default (your onsubmit attribute). Use a separate js file.

Comment: To see the error rightclick the popup, then Inspect, check the console.